# Card hover effect text pushing other texts

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Hi I'm trying to do a hover effect on my card to push the texts up when hover is true.

but I’m having difficulty I can move the text div, but the other text divs don’t and then my text is over the texts:
 [image]

code:

```
  <div
    className="a"
    onMouseOver={() => updateHoveredCards('card1', true)}
    onMouseOut={() => updateHoveredCards('card1', false)}
  >
    <div className="title">
      <p className="text-title">Emasa em Ação</p>
    </div>
    <div className="content-header">
      <h3 className="content-text" style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
      Emasa corrigiu vazamento no bairro Pedro Jerônimo
      </h3>
      <p className="date-text" style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
        <span>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            className=""
            icon={faClock}
            size="lg"
            fixedWidth
            color="#fff"
          />
        </span>
        2020
      </p>
    </div>
    <div className="content-spoiler">
    <p>show this text bottom on hover show this text bottom on hover</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
  & .a {
    grid-area: a;
    position:relative;
    background-image: url(${({ bgOne }) => bgOne});
  } 
& .content-spoiler{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    display:flex;
    max-width:300px;
    background:red;
    ${({ isHover }) =>
    isHover &&
    `
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    bottom:30px;
    `}
  }
  & .text-title {
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    line-height: 13px;
    pointer-events: auto;
    background-position: top center;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #009ffd, #2a2a72);
    animation: ${HeaderKeyFrame} 5s ease infinite;
    background-size: 150% 100%;
    color: #fff;
  }
  & .content-text {
    max-width: 300px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.07692308rem !important;
    font-family: Roboto Slab, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  & .date-text {
    max-width: 250px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 0.6692308rem !important;
    font-family: sans-serif, serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    & > span {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
  }
```

code example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-snowflake-4dwpy

I basically defined my container as relative

and my div as absolute with bottom: 0 and then on hover bottom: 30

Comment: From what I see your rule only applies to the `<p>` element inside  `.content-spoiler`. You want all the elements to move? You'd have to use the hover of the `.a` element.

Comment: It seems you haven't bind other element with the hover styles, by the way you never set styles like this cause once you change the DOM you must adjust the css as well, nesting-selector is not a good solution for complex component (whole component)

Comment: could you help me how can i solve this? I'm not getting it :(

Comment: @Mihail Minkov .a is my container card

Comment: I suggest you look into CSSinJS. With Emotion, Styled Components, and JSS, there really is no need to be using CSS style sheets anymore.

Comment: @JMadelaine i go check thanks .

Comment: @MykonSpt just to confirm, what is the desired behavior? You want all the text to move upwards when you hover?

Comment: yess mihail yes, i have 3 texts

one being only visible on hover and pushing the others up

"as if it were an animation appearing the text"